# Lift VisualStudio write lock on an addin dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, add-in

I am trying to find my way around the addin concept of VisualStudio 2010 but I keep on getting the same error when I compile the solution:

> "unable to delete file '.\bin\VSA.dll'. Access to the path [...] is denied"

I suspected this would happen when the addin is loaded in the "dev instance" of Visual Studio while I try to compile the solution, but the addin seems to be correctly ticked out in the "Add-In Manager" and the .Addin file contains `<LoadBehavior>0</LoadBehavior>` which should be right.

Any idea what could be causing the lock or how to track down what is? Thanks!

Comment: Ever find a simplet way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restart VS for the addin to get unloaded, ticking out the checkbox won't unload the assembly from devenv.exe.

What seems to be working for me is to have the addin ticked out and start 2 instances of VS one with the adding project opened and one to debug the addin in.
Then enable the addin in the second instance to trigger the addin's initialization and debug it. 
Disable the addin in the second instance of VS, close the VS.
Recompile the addin project in the first instance, start a second instance again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was indeed not disabling it before closing VS each time. It is somehow disturbing not to be able to do some debug-trial-and-error programming and I'm surprised nobody improved this already... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way is to tick off the checkbox, close Visual Studio, delete the output files and finally restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) is a useful program for when you're unable to build because your dlls are locked.

Comment: Unlocker was unable to delete the dll.